# How to check Android OS version of bluestacks Emulator

Tags: android, bluestacks

I searched a lot for this in Google, but no hope, how to check the OS version of Bluestacks emulator in Windows? There is a video in YouTube for checking bluestack version, but not the Android version used in it.
I went to settings – > Advanced settings, but there was no tab corresponding to `About` tab which is found in an Android emulator like in the case of Genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install Terminal Emulator from Play Store, open the application and type:

`getprop ro.build.version.release`
you will get something like: `4.4.4` for KitKat.

or
`getprop ro.build.version.sdk` for getting the sdk version which will return `19`

Answer (score 25):

There is an easier way of getting to know the android version without having to install any application.

There are some scripts (php/js) that can detect your android version while visiting websites:

Try; http://demo.mobiledetect.net/ Or; 
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Thanks! Such an easy solution.

Answer (score 12):

Open a browser in Bluestacks and go to http://demo.mobiledetect.net

I have tested this on multiple devices of which the Android version is known, and it is accurate.
Currently responds to Bluestacks as v4.4.2 (Kitkat)

Answer (score 7):

Without any installation, you could use your adb commands.

For example, for your main emulator

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

For your multi emulators add up by 10,

```
adb -s emulator-5564 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s emulator-5564 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
adb -s emulator-5574 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s emulator-5574 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
//... so on
```

You could also do the shell commands by their local ip,

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5555 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5555 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5565 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5565 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5575 shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s 127.0.0.1:5575 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
//... so on
```

Answer (score 0):

just use Droid Info .. which gives you alot of Information quite easely.
[image]